# getting class attributes in particular order

Tags: python, class, attributes

I'm trying to find a ways to filter & sort the values of a class's attributes in a list.

Here's what I made:

```
[foo_class.__dict__[key] for key in foo_class.__dict__.keys() if key in my_bar_list]
```

`my_bar_list` is a list containing some (not all) of the class attributes, in a special order.

Is there a Pythonic way to sort `foo_class` attributes in `my_bar_list` order?

Comment: Note that you can leave out `.keys()` - iterating over a dictionary iterates over keys by default. Also, per [PEP-8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), that should be `FooClass`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wouldn't it be simpler to just do:

```
 [foo_class.__dict__[key] for key in my_bar_list if hasattr(foo_class, key)]
```

That way you preserve your initial order without having to sort another time.

Comment: +1 Iterate over the ordered list, not the arbitrarily ordered list.

Comment: Works perfectly! I also added a condition to the list comprehension.. if useful to someone, here's my final code: `[foo_class.__dict__[key] if hasattr(foo_class, key) else '' for key in my_bar_list]`